# Android Firebase ChildEventListener onChildRemoved dataSnapshot content

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have used firebase onChildAdded and onChildChanged both seem very important since they provide information through dataSnaphot object, but incase of onChildRemoved I'm wondering what its purpose is because already that child is gone and I am curious what the dataSnapshot provides.

Comment: onChildRemoved should return a datasnapshot with information about the child removed

Comment: i'm not trying to be mean but you can test it your own self

Comment: @OussemaAroua you're not definitely trying to be mean, and I did tried after just asking I thought when a child is removed its gone, but onChildRemoved() method gives you one last chance to clean its mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener.html#onChildRemoved(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot)) the `DataSnapshot` for `onChildRemoved` is:

> An immutable snapshot of the data at the child that was removed.

So this contains the data that was removed. Mostly you'll use the key `DataSnapshot.getKey()` to remove the UI elements corresponding to the data.